# I want to pull a report from multiple sql servers, where the Database owner and job owner is not SA

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

I want to pull a report from multiple sql servers,
where the Database owner and job owner is not SA.

I need a report from a Central monitoring server, if the database owner and job owner is not SA, I need to get in the report.

Can any one help me to get this report.

Thanks
Bahrath

Comment: what do you plan to use to do your report ? SSRS, PowerBI, Old plain SQL Queries ?

Comment: not a report we need get an email, is there any possibilities, we cannot use ssrs

Comment: As a start, you could try running this query - SELECT name FROM msdb..sysjobs where owner_sid not in (select sid from Master.dbo.syslogins where name = 'SA')

Answer (score 2):

Do you want one email per server or one email for all servers?

One per server is easy, push out a job that does your check and send the email using sp_send_dbmail. This can be done through an MSX server if you want.

One mail for all servers requires a client that query each servers and collect the info and finally send email. Powershell is likely a good idea.